# Easiest way to count duplicate rows across multiple columns in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have an Excel file with 4 columns and 20,000 rows of data. I need to count the number of duplicate rows, meaning rows with the same information in all 4 columns.

For example:

| DOB | Name | Salary | City |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7/31/1975 | John | 45,000 | Chicago |
| 4/15/1963 | Blaire | 53,000 | Los Angeles |
| 7/31/1975 | John | 45,000 | Chicago |

Counting the table above would return 2. Is there a formula I can execute to do this for me in Excel? I've only found information to count duplicates from one column.

Comment: Add a fifth that concatenates the previous four then count from there?

Comment: @findwindow Concatenation without non-participant delimiters is not reliable.

Comment: @ExcelHero - what do you mean "non-participant delimiters"?

Comment: @BruceWayne Delimiters (the pipe character (|) for example) that are guaranteed to not be part of the text concatenated.

Comment: Not sure why that's an issue but Hero is more knowledgeable than I so I guess just add a `|` for each column when you concatenate.

Comment: @findwindow @BruceWayne Remove the pipe from each of these concatenated rows and ask yourself if the rows are duplicate:  `ab|a` and `a|ba`

Comment: Ah. Makes sense. Excellent point. Well, in this case, the data suggests that won't be an issue ^_^

Comment: These *de-duping* algorithms can get relatively complicated quickly, depending on how reliable your data is. For example, `John` misspelled as `Jon` - might be the same guy - in other words, a duplicate row. Step through what you would need to do manually to *reliably* remove the duplicate entries; then write a custom function / macro to automate the process. There is no out-of-the-box excel formula that will do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

Add a reference (**Tools** -> **References...**) to **Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects**; the latest version, usually `6.1`.

Then you can execute the following SQL statement against your data:

```sql
SELECT DOB, Name, Salary, City, COUNT(*) AS CountOfDuplicates
FROM [Sheet1$]
GROUP BY DOB, Name, Salary, City
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

using code like the following:

```vba
Const filename = "C:\path\to\excel\file.xlsx"
Const sheetname = "Sheet1"

Dim connectionString As String
connectionString = _
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=""" & filepath & """;" & _
    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=Yes"""
    
    ' If your data is in a macro-enabled file (.xlsm), the previous line should
    ' look like this:
    ' "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=No"""
    
Dim sql As String
sql = _
    "SELECT DOB, Name, Salary, City, COUNT(*) AS CountOfDuplicates " & _
    "FROM [" & sheetname & "$] " & _
    "GROUP BY DOB, Name, Salary, City " & _
    "HAVING COUNT(*) > 1"

' If your data is only part of the worksheet, you can specify the range in the FROM clause as follows:
'    "FROM [" & sheetname & "!B10:E20000$] " & _

Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open sql, connectionString
```

With a populated recordset in hand, you can do a number of things:

- Iterate over every row, using the Recordset's [**BOF** and **EOF** properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/bof-eof-properties-ado), the [**MoveNext**](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/movefirst-movelast-movenext-and-moveprevious-methods-ado) method; and the [**Fields** property and collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/fields-collection-ado)
- Paste it into an Excel range using the Range [**CopyFromRecordset**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copyfromrecordset) method
- Generate a 2-dimensional array, using the [**GetRows**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/getrows-method-ado) method
- Generate a complete string, using the [**GetString**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/getstring-method-ado) method

---

**References:**

Microsoft Access SQL (used when querying Excel files):

- [Basic concepts, vocabulary, and syntax](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/access-sql-basic-concepts-vocabulary-and-syntax-444d0303-cde1-424e-9a74-e8dc3e460671#:%7E:text=Relational%20database%20programs%2C%20such%20as,such%20as%20ISO%20and%20ANSI.)
- [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/microsoft-access-sql-reference)

ADODB:

- [**Recordset** object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordset-object-ado)

  - [**Open** method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/open-method-ado-connection)
  - [**Fields** property and collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/fields-collection-ado)
  - [**BOF** / **EOF** properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/bof-eof-properties-ado)
  - [**GetRows** method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/getrows-method-ado)
  - [**GetString** method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/getstring-method-ado)

Excel:

- [**Range** object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)) — [**CopyFromRecordset** method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copyfromrecordset)

Answer (score 0):

You can just do a `Countifs` over the whole range

`=Countifs(A2:A6,A2:A6,B2:B6,B2:B6,...,ZZ2:ZZ6)`

(Enter as an array with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>)

Basically, if you want to compare columns A, B, C, and D for exact data, just do
 `=COUNTIFS(A2:A5,A2:A5,B2:B5,B2:B5,C2:C5,C2:C5,D2:D5,D2:D5)`

(entered as array)

Comment: This doesn't count duplicates.  It returns 1 if any data is in the columns, or zero otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer was almost right, but I would have used the formula a bit differently. Assuming that all the columns actually have a value in them, You can do this using the COUNTIFS function which takes in a list of ranges and conditions

example
COUNTIFS (range1, condition1, range2, condition2...)

If you wanted to get the count of rows that were identical for column B, C,& D you can do something like this:

COUNTIFS(B:B,B2,C:C,C2,D:D,D3)

The above is essentially saying give me a count of all rows that have the same  values that are in cell B2, C2, and D2. The count returned also include the current row, which means that if there are no duplicates it returns 1, and if there are any duplicates it would return # of duplicated rows.

NOTE: If one of the columns is blank or empty it will mess with the function's calculations and return a 0 for that row. If you are using data that could include blank values in one of the columns you have to do something a bit more tricky like wrapping the values you are checking against in an if statement to search for the value if it exists or a blank space if it doesn't

like this:
=COUNTIFS(B:B,IF(B2<>"",B2,""),C:C,IF(C2<>"",C2,""))

Note 2: The 2nd formula can result in a huge number also like 1,000,000+ if you use it on a column that is totally blank. it is essentially returning the number of blank rows in the excel sheet. max number of rows in an excel sheet are 1084576